Java Jersey Client to Server Multipart POST Request Results in HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type
I'm working with two Java containers where the first container (Client) sends a list of images to a service exposed by the second container (Server) using a multipart POST request. However, the server always responds with a 415 "Unsupported Media Type" error.
Here is the code for the client:
public class ClientController {
    
    public List<...> doRequest(List<InputStream> images, Integer value1, double value2) {
        try (MultiPart multiPart = new FormDataMultiPart()) {

            Client client = ClientBuilder
                .newBuilder()
                .register(MultiPartFeature.class)
                .build();
            
            WebTarget target = client.target(baseURI + "/service/value1/" + value1 + "/value2/" + value2);

            int index = 0;
            for (InputStream image : images) {
                StreamDataBodyPart bodyPart = new StreamDataBodyPart("file" + index, image);
                multiPart.bodyPart(bodyPart);
                index++;
            }

            Response response = target.request().post(Entity.entity(multiPart, multiPart.getMediaType()));

            if (response.getStatus() != Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode()) {
                // Handle error
            }
        }
    }
}

And here is the server code that receives and processes the request:
@Path("service")
public class ServerController {
    
    @POST
    @Path("/value1/{value1}/value2/{value2}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getResponse(@PathParam("value1") int value1, @PathParam("value2") double value2, MultiPart multiPart) {
        List<InputStream> images = multiPart
            .getBodyParts()
            .stream()
            .map(bodyPart -> bodyPart.getEntityAs(InputStream.class))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        // Process images and generate response
    }
}

I have already registered the MultiPartFeature on the client side, but the server still responds with a 415 error. What could be the cause of this issue? How can I correctly send a list of images as a multipart POST request from the client to the server?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!
